# Exercise in Chapter 1 of Switzer's Algebraic Topology book

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm trying to answer the following question: (I've added details to make the post self-contained.)

Fix two pointed spaces $(K,k_0)$ and $(L,l_0)$ and define two functors $F_K$, $F_L$ from the category of pointed spaces + continuous functions preserving base point $\mathscr{PT}$ to the category of pointed sets + functions preserving base point $\mathscr{PS}$ as follows:

$(X,x_0)  \longmapsto F_K(X,x_0) = [ K,k_0; X,x_0]$, here $[ \cdot, \cdot ]$ represents homotopy classes of maps.

$f:(X,x_0) \rightarrow (Y,y_0) \longmapsto F_K(f)$,
where $F_K(f)[g] = [f \circ g] \in [K,k_0;Y,y_0]$ for $[g]\in [K,k_0;X,x_0]$

The functor $F_L$ is similarly defined (replacing $(K,k_0)$ with $(L,l_0)$).

Next, define a natural transformation as follows. Suppose
$\phi: (K,k_0) \rightarrow (L,l_0)$ is a morphism in $\mathscr{PT}$. Then
define $T_\phi:F_L \rightarrow F_K$ by

$T_\phi (X,x_0)[g] = [g\circ \phi] \in [K,k_0;X,x_0]$,

for every $(X,x_0)$ and $[g] \in F_L(X,x_0)$. (Switzer shows that this satisfies the properties of a natural transformation.)

Finally, the actual question: **Show that $\mathbf{ \phi:(K,k_0) \rightarrow (L,l_0)}$ is a homotopy equivalence if and only if $T_\phi$ is a natural equivalence ($\mathbf{T_\phi(X,x_0)}$ is a bijection for every $\mathbf{ (X,x_0)}$).**

My attempt at a solution for the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction: (for the sake of reducing typing, I am going to ignore writing the base points)

Let $\phi: K \rightarrow L$ be a homotopy equivalence. Then there exists $\psi: L \rightarrow K$ such that $\psi \circ \phi \simeq id_K$ and $\phi \circ \psi \simeq id_L$. I will now define a bijection $\Phi: [L;X] \cong [K;X]$. For $[h] \in [L;X]$ define $\Phi[h] := [h\circ \phi]\in [K;X]$. To see that this is 1-1, let $[h_1]$ and $[h_2]$ be in $[L;X]$ and assume that $\Phi[h_1] = \Phi[h_2]$ then $[h_1 \circ \phi] = [h_2 \circ \phi] \Rightarrow [h_1 \circ \phi \circ \psi ] = [h_2 \circ \phi \circ \psi ] \Rightarrow [h_1] = [h_2]$. Next, for onto, let $[g] \in [K;X]$, and note $[g] = [g \circ \psi \circ \phi] = \Phi[g \circ \psi]$.

So, if $\phi : K \rightarrow L$ is a homotopy equivalence then $[K;X] \cong [L;X]$ for all $X$.

Question: Does anyone see anything wrong with my solution to this direction?

For the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction I am completely stuck at: Let $T_\phi: F_L \rightarrow F_K$ be an equivalence for all $X$; that is $[K;X] \cong [L;X]$ for all $X$. :)

Question: Can anyone give me a nudge for this direction?

Comment: A hint: the statement is true for all $X$, so pick an $X$ which will help you out. You are looking for a map $L \to K$ to be a candidate for a homotopy inverse to $\phi$.

Comment: I had considered picking $K$ for $X$, giving $[K;K]\cong [L;K]$, but I cannot figure out how to use this. (Assuming that is the $X$ which you are suggesting.)

Comment: If you let $K=X$, then you need to choose a map $K \to K$ (which map?), which will then correspond to a map $L \to K$ (what's the correspondence?).

Comment: Thank you for the additional nudge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but I suggest to use the notation introduced in your question. That is, use $T_\phi(X)$ instead of $\Phi$ (base point suppressed). Proceed as follows:

1. Switzer's construction works for *any* $\theta : A \to B$ to give $T_\theta(X) : [B,X] \to [A,X]$.
2. Clearly $T_\theta(X)$ only depends on the pointed homotopy class $[\theta]$ of $\theta$.
3. Obviously  $T_{id}(X) = id$ and $T_{\chi \circ \theta}(X) = T_\theta(X) \circ T_\chi(X)$.
4. If $\phi$ is a pointed homotopy equivalence and $\psi$ is a homotopy inverse, then  $T_\phi(X) \circ T_\psi(X) = T_{\psi \circ \phi}(X) = T_{id}(X) = id$, similarly $T_\psi(X) \circ T_\phi(X) = id$. This means that $T_\phi(X)$ and $T_\psi(X)$ are bijections which are inverse to each other.

For the converse, take $X = K$ and let $\psi : L \to K$ represent the unique homotopy class in $[L;K]$ such that $T_\phi(K)([\psi]) =  [id] \in [K;K]$ (recall that $T_\phi(K) : [L;X] \to [K;X]$ is a bijection for all $X$). Then $[\psi] \circ [\phi] = [\psi \circ \phi] = T_\phi([\psi]) = [id]$. By 2. we get $T_\phi(L) \circ T_\psi(L) = T_{\psi \circ \phi}(L) = id$, thus $T_\psi(L) = T_\phi(L)^{-1}$, i.e. $T_\psi(L) : [K;L] \to [L;L]$ is a bijection. Let $\phi' : K \to L$ represent the unique homotopy class in $[K;L]$ such that $T_\psi(L)([\phi']) =  [id] \in [L;L]$. This means $[\phi'] \circ [\psi] = [id]$. Thus $[\psi]$ has a rigt and a left inverse. It is a general theorem of category theory that if a morphism $v : B \to A$ has a right inverse $u : A \to B$ (i.e. $v \circ u = id_A$) and a left inverse $u' : A \to B$ (i.e. $u' \circ v = id_B$), then $v$ is an isomorphism and $u = u' = v^{-1}$.

To see this, note that $u = id_B \circ u = (u' \circ v) \circ u = u' \circ (v \circ u) = u' \circ id_A = u'$.

Comment: Thank you for the details.